# mvn archetype:generate gives missing class plexus PrompterException error

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

I am using maven 3.0.3. I am running mvn archetype:generate and I am getting the following error:-

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate failed: Unable to load the mojo 'generate' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0'. A required class is missing: org/codehaus/plexus/components/interactivity/PrompterException

I tried cleaning the maven-archetype-plugin directory in the repository. No Luck!

Your help appreciated!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? Using a repository manager ?

Comment: Yes I am behind a proxy. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't but have configured correctly your settings.xml ?

Comment: yes i verified settings.xml, and the proxy and other details are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to extends your command line

```
mvn archetpe:2.2:generate ...
```